# How can i get server and or database usages in Azure using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I am trying to get database usage and sql server usage using az cli .
For database usage i am using

```
  az sql db list-usages --name $database --resource-group $resourceGroup --server $server
```

but this doesnt really give back what the portal shows , as in Percentage used , Used space in GB , Remaining Space in GB Allocated Space and Max Storage in GB.

How can i get these values using az cli ?

Comment: Why don't you use PowerShell script instead of CLI script?

Answer (score 0):

There are some commands given in this documentation for Azure CLI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/service-page/sql?view=azure-cli-latest

```
az sql show-usage \
--resource-group <resource-group-name> \
--server-name <server-name> \
--database-name <database-name> \
--metric-names "DTU consumption", "Storage usage" \
--start-date 2024-02-01 \
--end-date 2024-02-15
```

You might need to play around with the metric-names argument in the above command. Example: "CPU percentage", "IO read", "IO write"

Comment: im more interested in the percentage of space used. How can i get the metric name , is there a list of some sort ?

Comment: that gives an error : it says location is required and --usage/U is required

Comment: `az monitor metrics list --resource "/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{server_name}" --metric "SuccessfulConnections" "DTU_consumption_percent" --interval PT1H --start-time 2024-02-01T02:00:00Z --end-time 2024-02-33T01:00:00Z --output table`        You can write a script by including this command and the percentage calculation logic and execute that script. Check this out as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-list

Comment: get an error:    z : az : ERROR: (BadRequest) Failed to find metric configuration for provider: Microsoft.Sql, resource Type: servers, metric: SuccessfulConnections, Valid metrics: dtu_consumption_percent,storage_used,dtu_used

Comment: this is for servers, what about app services , wont this Microsoft.Sql/servers change ?